# What statistical tests can I use to compare two different ml algorithm on a dataset that has been augmented using two different approaches?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, python, data-mining

I used SMOTE and ADASYN on a dataset separately and used Random Forest and KNN on them. Both giving quite close accuracy(RF= 97.75 %, KNN= 97.22% where SMOTE was used) & (RF=97.67% and KNN=97.42% where ADASYN was used). Now I learned about statistical tests which can be used to compare two different models using single dataset. But in my case, because I used two different augmentation technique, my dataset also became different to some extent. Is there a way or statistical test that I can say that for my dataset, SMOTE is better than ADASYN or they are statistically not different?

Comment: Well, you didn’t augment your test set. (Right? It wouldn’t make sense to…) So you’re evaluating two models on the same test set, giving you the usual options in terms of tests.